# creating a pause menu in delphi

Tags: delphi

Background: I have created a maze game that is playable, however when the maze gets bigger there are more chances to go wrong and takes ages to reach the start of the maze again, I've been told that's really annoying.

Question: I want to create a pause game function that when the user presses the button key a menu pops up that allows the user to be able to either return to main menu or restart the maze.

I have very little knowledge on where to start this in the code as I don't want to mess up anything that has already been added.

I've added the draw maze //creates the maze, 
initialise visited and walk // removes the walls of the maze, 
Form key down//moves the player 
and Timer//collision detection procedures below.

hopefully someone can help?

Many Thanks.

```
`procedure TfrmMazeDesign.draw_maze(square_size: integer);
      var
        row, col : integer;


      begin
         // setup default walls as "WWWW" wall on all four sides.
        SetLength(Shapes,height+3, width+3, 2 ) ;

        for row := 1 to  height do
            begin
                for col := 1 to width+2 do
                  begin

                      Shapes[row,col,0]:= TShape.Create(Self);
                      Shapes[row,col,0].Parent := Self;

                      with Shapes[row,col,0] do
                      begin
                        Width := 5;
                        Height := square_size;
                        Left := 100+ ((col-1) * square_size);
                        Top := 50+ ((row-1) * square_size);
                        Brush.Color := RGB(255, 255,25);
                        Shape := stRectangle;
                      end;


                  end;
            end;


        for row := 1 to height+1  do
            begin
                for col := 1 to width+1 do
                  begin

                      Shapes[row,col,1]:= TShape.Create(Self);
                      Shapes[row,col,1].Parent := Self;

                      with Shapes[row,col,1] do
                      begin
                        Width := square_size;
                        Height := 5;
                        Left := 100+ ((col-1) * square_size);
                        Top :=  50+ ((row-1) * square_size);
                        Brush.Color := RGB(255, 255,25);
                        Shape := stRectangle;
                      end;

                 end;
          end;


      end;




procedure  TfrmMazeDesign.initialise_visited(var visited: Tvisited);

var
  row, col: integer;


begin

  for  row := 0 to height+2 do
    for col := 0 to width+2  do
      if (col = 0) or (row = 0) or (row = height+1) or (col= width+2) then
        visited[row,col] := True
      else
        visited[row,col] := False;



end;




procedure TFrmMazeDesign.walk(visited: Tvisited; x: integer; y:integer);
  var
    xx,yy, counter, ran_direction: integer;
    direction: Tstringlist;  //  1= Up, 2= right, 3 = down, 4 = left
    text: string;


begin
   visited[x,y] := True;
   direction  := TStringlist.Create;
   direction.Add('1');
   direction.Add('2');
   direction.Add('3');
   direction.Add('4');
   for counter := direction.Count - 1 downto 0 do
      direction.Exchange(counter, Random(counter+1));



   for counter := 0 to direction.Count-1 do
      begin
       ran_direction := StrtoInt(direction[counter]);
       if ran_direction= 1 then
          begin
            xx := x-1;
            yy := y
          end;
       if ran_direction = 2 then
          begin
            xx := x+1;
            yy := y
          end;
       if ran_direction = 3 then
          begin
            xx := x;
            yy := y-1
          end;
       if ran_direction= 4 then
          begin
            xx := x;
            yy := y+1
          end;


       if  visited[xx,yy] = False then
          begin
            if xx = x then
                shapes[x,Max(yy,y),0].visible := False;
            if yy = y then
                shapes[Max(xx,x),y,1].visible := False;
             walk (visited, xx,yy)
           end;
      end;

end;


procedure TfrmMazeDesign.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
  begin
case Key of
    VK_UP:
    direction := 1;
    VK_DOWN:
    direction := 2;
    VK_LEFT:
    direction := 3;
    VK_RIGHT:
    direction := 4;
  end;

end;

procedure TfrmMazeDesign.FormOpen(Sender: TObject);
var

  block_height: integer;
  xx,yy: integer;
  visited: Tvisited;
  monster, monster2: TMonster;

  Shape_height : integer;
  Shape_Width : integer;
  imgfinish_height : integer;
  maze_width : integer;


begin

  width := frmdifficulty.ScrollBar1.Position;
  height := frmdifficulty.ScrollBar1.Position;
  maze_width := 650;

  block_height := maze_width div width;
  Shape_height :=  round( block_height * 0.5);
  imgfinish_height := round(block_height * 0.5);

  draw_maze(block_height);
  SetLength(visited, height+10, width+10) ;
  initialise_visited(visited);
  walk(visited,3,3);
  ShpUser.height := Shape_height;
  ShpUser.Width  := Shape_height;
  imgfinish.width := Shape_height;
  imgfinish.height := shape_height;


  ShpUser.Shape := UShapeEditor.frmShape.shpShape.Shape;
  ShpUser.Brush.color := UShapeEditor.frmShape.shpShape.Brush.color;

  FDateTimeTo := StrToDateTime(FormatDateTime('dd' + FormatSettings.DateSeparator + 'mm' +
  FormatSettings.DateSeparator + 'yyyy', Now)); Incsecond(time,120);

  Timer1.Enabled := True;


  monster := TMonster.Create(Self);
  monster.Parent := Self;
  monster.SetSizes(width, height, shape_height, 55+ maze_width + 10,665);
  monster.start;

  monster2 := TMonster.Create(Self);
  monster2.Parent := Self;
  monster2.SetSizes(width, height, shape_height, 50+ maze_width + 10,565);
  monster2.start;

  end;

procedure TfrmMazeDesign.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);

var IntersectionRect: TRect;
    collision, test_collision : boolean;
    up : boolean;
    right : boolean;
    max_width, max_height : integer;
    xx, yy : integer ;
    aRect1: TRect;
    buttonSelected : Integer;
    collisionend: boolean;
    frmMazeDesign: TfrmMazeDesign;
    row, col, hoz_vert : integer;
begin

  hoz_vert := 0;

  xx := 0;
  yy := 0;

  case direction of
    1:begin        //Up
          yy := -3;
      end;
    2: begin       //down
          yy := + 3;
       end;

    3:  begin      //left
           xx := -3;
       end;

    4:  begin        //right
           xx := + 3;
        end;

  end;


  repeat
    if hoz_Vert = 0 then begin
      max_width := width +3;
      max_height := Height+1;
    end else begin
      max_width := width+2;
      max_height := Height+2;
    end;

    row := 1;
    repeat
      col := 1;


      repeat
        aRect1 := Rect(ShpUser.Left+xx, ShpUser.Top+yy, ShpUser.Left+ShpUser.width+xx, ShpUser.top+ ShpUser.Height+yy);
        if Shapes[row,col,hoz_vert].visible = True then
          collision :=  IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, aRect1, Shapes[row,col,hoz_vert].BoundsRect)  ;

        col := col + 1;

      until (collision) or (col = max_width);
      row := row + 1 ;
    until (collision) or (row = max_height);
    hoz_vert := hoz_vert +1;
  until (collision) or (hoz_vert = 2);

  if (collision = False) and (direction <> 0) then begin
    ShpUser.Top := ShpUser.Top + yy;
    ShpUser.Left := ShpUser.Left + xx;
  end;


      if IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, imgfinish.BoundsRect, Shpuser.BoundsRect) then
      begin
      Collisionend := true;
      if collisionend = true  then
       frmfinish.Show;
        direction:= 0;
      end;`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively straightforward to add to your program, which is already event driven. In summary you need to do the following:

1. Add a `Boolean` flag, perhaps named `Paused`, set to `False` when the game starts.
2. When the user presses the pause button, set the `Paused` flag to `True`.
3. When the user presses the resume button, set the `Paused` flag to `False`.
4. In the time event handler, check the `Paused` flag before updating the positions. If the `Paused` flag is `True`, then simply exit from the timer event handler before doing anything else.

Comment: Wouldn't it be even easier to temporarily disable the timer when game is paused?

Comment: Well, yes that may well be simpler

Comment: After thinking about it, adding a new `Boolean` flag has the advantage of not loosing the `TTimer`'s stride, if anything relies on that.